# iOS 7 status bar for UI development

Tags: ios, ui

I am creating some UI designs for an app, but I am struggling to find a template for the time, carrier, battery etc. bar at the top of the iPhone's display.

Where could I find a copy of this bar so that I can add it to my designs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an iOS 7 status bar with the default UINavigationController background colour:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, much appreciated. I found a transparent backed version.